# Toggle button onClick method does not work

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have toggle button which has `android:onClick=onToggleClicked`. I tried to reference the `onToggleClicked` method from the java code but the problem is, eclipse underscore the `onToggleClicked` with red and does not recognizes it. How to fix this error.

Imports:

```
import java.util.Set;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.os.Build;
```

JavaCode:

```
    if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        tb_OnOFF.setEnabled(false);
        btnFind.setEnabled(false);
        btnPaired.setEnabled(false);
        tvStatusCaption.setText("Status: Not Supported.");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Device Does Not Support " +
                "Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        public void onToggleClicked (View view) {
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
            if (on) {
                //enable bluetooth                  
            }

            if (!on) {
                //disable bluetooth
            }
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btnToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="@string/toggle_turn_on"
    android:textOff="@string/toggle_turn_off"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked" />
```

Comment: Please add the imports you are using at the top of you class.

Comment: how can you create a method inside a method??
the onToggleClicked method must be directly inside the activity. Not inside a method itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE THIS

```
mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mToggleButton.isChecked()) {
        //your code

    }
    else{
        //your code
    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

`onToggleClicked` is a public method and needs to be attached to your `Activity`. You cannot use this method as an inner method inside `onCreate` method.